# How can I make file editing conditional?

Tags: php, if-statement, replace

Here is my code:

```
$file = '/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf';
// Laravel Projects
$newDirectory = "<Directory $path/public>
                     Allow Override all
                     Require all granted
                  </Directory>";
$virtualHost = file_put_contents($file,str_replace("</VirtualHost>","$newDirectory\n\n</VirtualHost>",file_get_contents($file)));
```

It works as well. As you can see, it opens `000-default.conf` file *(in linux)* and appends a new directory at the end of `<VirtualHost>` block.

My problem is, sometimes the rest of the code throws an error and when I run the whole script again, code above will append that directory twice.

How can I add a condition on the way of `file_put_contents` to check first if if the same directory isn't exist, then append it, otherwise don't do anything?

Comment: Surely fix the code that throws the error? If run the script multiple times, it's safe to assume that you'll run into duplicates. Also, on a side note, why not use the `FILE_APPEND` flag?

Comment: @JustBaron I meant throws a warning and stops *(not error)*. In other word, sometimes my code throws you should pass parameter x as a get argument. Also  I don't know how exactly should I use `FILE_APPEND` flag in this case.

Comment: Check for the presence of `<Directory $path/public>` before you overwrite the file.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The question is exactly how? How can I add an `if` statement into `file_put_contents` ?

Comment: ^ You could use something like: `if(strpos($fileContents, "$newDirectory\n\n</VirtualHost>") !== TRUE)...file_put_contents().`

Comment: @JustBaron You mean I have to run `file_get_content` first and do something on the content? Can't I use `function(){}` into `file_put_contents` ?

Comment: @stack: I'm surprised you need to ask this, looking at the answers you've given in the past.

Comment: @stack See AlivetoDie or Steve's answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
<?php
 $file = '/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf';
 // Laravel Projects
 $newDirectory = "<Directory $path/public>
                 Allow Override all
                 Require all granted
              </Directory>";

  $virtualHostContent = file_get_contents($file);
  if( strpos($virtualHostContent,"<Directory $path/public>") === false) {
     $virtualHost = file_put_contents($file,str_replace("</VirtualHost>","$newDirectory\n\n</VirtualHost>",$virtualHostContent));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Would you not store the file contents in a variable, for reuse?

Answer (score 1):

This is what try catch blocks are Made for. I am on mobile so I can't provide you the code but here is a little idea for you:

Save the original file content and wrap your code in a try catch block. If an error occurs then reset your file to the original content in the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I add a condition on the way of file_put_contents to check first if if the same directory isn't exist,

Provided the file isnt huge, you can just read it into a string and check with strpos:

```
if(strpos(file_get_contents($file), "<Directory $path/public>") === false){
    $virtualHost = file_put_contents(...);
}
```